# How to insert an IDENT_CURRENT on INSERT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I'm creating a Stored Procedure in MS SQL SERVER 2008 to enter the clients. Here is the important part of my code:

```
INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (@nameEnt, @iniEnt, @LastNEnt1, @suffixEnt);
INSERT INTO Patient VALUES (@housing, @dob, IDENT_CURRENT('Entity'));
INSERT INTO Direction VALUES (@postAdd, @city, @state, @zip, IDENT_CURRENT('Entity'));
INSERT INTO PatientSecure VALUES (IDENT_CURRENT('Patient'), @idSecure, @contractNo, @groupNo, @coverage)
```

It doesn't work, probably because I only have seen IDENT_CURRENT used on SELECT. However, I need to do something similar, which the **idEntity** generated on **Entity** after the first line in inserted, be on the **Patient** table on the row **idEntity** which has to be the **same id** generated on **Entity**. The same thing on Direction and PatientSecure.

If there is a better way to do this, please suggest it.

Please help! and be nice :)
Thank You

Comment: Did the answers help? Were they nice? If so, some feedback would be appropriate. If not, feedback is still appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `IDENT_CURRENT` returns a value that is independent of session and scope. A different user might cause the value the change between your `INSERT` statements.

You can use `Scope_Identity()`:

```
declare @EntityId as Int;
INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (@nameEnt, @iniEnt, @LastNEnt1, @suffixEnt);
set @EntityId = Scope_Identity();
declare @PatientId as Int;
INSERT INTO Patient VALUES (@housing, @dob, @EntityId);
set @PatientId = Scope_Identity();
INSERT INTO Direction VALUES (@postAdd, @city, @state, @zip, @EntityId);
INSERT INTO PatientSecure VALUES (@PatientId, @idSecure, @contractNo, @groupNo, @coverage)
```

Or you could use an `OUTPUT` clause on the `INSERT`s to save the appropriate values.  While it may be overkill in this case, it is a valuable tool to know.  It works with `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, handles multiple rows and (where applicable) provides access to *before* and *after* values.

Comment: thanks .it help to solve bulk insert problem

Answer (score -1):

I would replace all of your calls to `ident_current('some_table')` with calls to `scope_identity()`.

Comment: Since the identity value for `Entity` is used twice and the `Patient` identity value is used after an intervening `INSERT` a simple substitution is unlikely to provide the correct results.

Comment: You're right; I read the question too quickly and assumed that each successive insert was using the identity value of the insert before it.